# How can I determine how many worksheets there are in an Excel workbook?

Tags: c#, excel

thanks in advance for your help. I want to loop through all worksheets in a workbook. Unfortunately, I don't know how many worksheets there are in a given workbook. Right now I use the following technique to enumerate through all worksheets:

```
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1;
xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet2;
xlWorkSheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet3;
xlWorkSheet3 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(3);
```

Is there a method that returns the number of worksheets in a workbook?

Answer (score 5):

Use `Excel.Workbook` and then you can use the `Workbook.Sheets.Count()` in a `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: Please tick the hollow tick :o)  It helps others.

Comment: .Count property in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel V1.9.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The [Worksheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb215242.aspx) property has a collection of the worksheets .

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet xlworksheet in xlworkbook.Worksheets)
{
    //xlworksheet code here
}
```

Or, get the count value and use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Googling this results in either this page, or several others where you have to use VBA or C# or start mucking about in the Name Manager in Excel.

Anyone looking for a quick and dirty solution:

Open the xlsx file with 7zip and navigate to xl\worksheets. 
In there you should see all the sheets, and if you select those 7zip will count them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a module in the workbook you want to count the total sheets of,
Then type the below code and hit <kbd>run</kbd>

```
Public Sub CountWorksheets()
       MsgBox "Total Sheets count:" & Application.Sheets.Count

End Sub
```

You'll get a relevant output like below

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

We can now use: `int Workbook.Sheets.Count`

Answer (score 0):

**I use this code:**

```
//Create application.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

//Opening excel book
Workbook ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelFileLocation, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

//Getting sheets count
int sheetsCount = ObjWorkBook.Worksheets.Count;
```

For this code to work, you need to install the package using NuGet - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel